# More than one yml in spring cloud gateway

Tags: java, spring-cloud-gateway

I have to configure a lot of routes, but include all of them in just one yml will be hard for maintenance. Is there a way to split the route in more than one yml? I would like to split by context.

Comment: Create multiple yml files with different names `application-route1.yml`, `application-route2.yml` etc., then just include them in `spring.profiles.active` of the main yml

Comment: I saw in spring repository that it is opened issues

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/831